# Exception Handling Advice

Tags: python, exception

I'm new to Python and making a small program that calculates how much is owed on a loan. I need help with exception handling within my program.

When I enter a non-numeric number, I have the program restart to the beginning tellingthe user to try again. Though when I enter all with numbers, nothing is calculated and takes me back to the beginning of the program. I need some guidance and need to know what I'm doing wrong.

```
permonthpayment = 0
loantotal = 0
monthlyinterestrate = 0
numberofpayments = 0 
loanyears = 0

while True:
    loantotal = input("How much money do you need loaned? ")
    loanyears = input("In how many years will full payment be fulfilled? ")
    monthlyinterestrate = input("What's the annual interest rate? (Enter as whole number) ")

try:
    loanyears = float(loanyears)
    loantotal = float(loantotal)
    monthlyinterestrate = float(monthlyinterestrate)
except:
    print("Please enter a valid number and try again.")
    continue

totalpayments = loanyears*12
percent = monthlyinterestrate/100

permonthpayment = (loantotal * (percent/12)) / (1-(1/(1 + (percent/12))) ** (loanyears * 12))
totalpayment = (permonthpayment) * totalpayments

print("You owe $" + str(round(permonthpayment, 2)), "each month")
print("You owe $" +str(round(totalpayment, 2)), "at the end of the pay period")
```

Comment: Your indenting is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Your code is looking pretty good, there's just one small change you need to get this thing running. Currently you are asking for user input inside of a `while` loop, but then you leave the `while` loop before verifying the input. Lets take a look at some proper input validation in python:

```
while True:
    try:
         loantotal = input("How much money do you need loaned? ")
         loanyears = input("In how many years will full payment be fulfilled? ")
         monthlyinterestrate = input("What's the annual interest rate? (Enter as whole number) ")
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")
        #better try again... Return to the start of the loop
        continue
    else:
        # the values were successfully parsed!
        #we're finished with input validation and ready to exit the loop.
        break 
# now we can continue on with the rest of our program
permonthpayment = (loantotal * (percent/12)) / (1-(1/(1 + (percent/12))) ** (loanyears * 12))
totalpayment = (permonthpayment) * totalpayments

print("You owe $" + str(round(permonthpayment, 2)), "each month")
print("You owe $" +str(round(totalpayment, 2)), "at the end of the pay period")
```

`while True:...` essentially translates to do ... forever unless you are explicitly told to stop. So in our case, we will ask the user for input forever, until they input values that do not result in a `ValueError`. The `ValueError` exception in python results from failure to cast a data type, or more specifically in our case from failure to convert the raw user input into floats.